# jUnits taking too long due to heap memory getting full

Tags: java, junit, heap-memory

For one of the projects I am working on, we have written jUnits that read requests from text files and then call methods. In the actual methods we are creating PDF reports, so the objects of Tables, Documents etc are getting created due to which the Heap memory available for jUnits gets exhausted very fast and the jUnits take a lot of time to complete.

Is there any way through which I can ensure that once a jUnit is executed, all the objects created for it get Garbage collected from memory?

I have tried using `System.gc()` the method in `@AfterClass` methods for each Test class, but it did not help. Also, tried by increasing the heap size but the same result.
Framework Used is `Spring-boot 1.4.0` and `JUnit` version is `4.12`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc()` doesn't guarantee that the garbage collector will run.

From the JUnit documentation

> By design, the tree of Test instances is built in one pass, then the tests are executed in a second pass. The test runner holds strong references to all Test instances for the duration of the test execution. This means that for a very long test run with many Test instances, none of the tests may be garbage collected until the end of the entire test run.
>
> Therefore, if you allocate external or limited resources in a test, you are responsible for freeing those resources. Explicitly setting an object to null in the tearDown() method, for example, allows it to be garbage collected before the end of the entire test run.

In short. Make sure you set object references to null when you are done with them